# I need help to use and install docker on Linux kUbuntu

Tags: python, linux, docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I need help installing docker on my KUbuntu.

I thought I had installed everything correctly, however when I get to the moment of creating the image, the following error occurs:

Command:

`docker build -t Image_Test:tag .`

Error:

`ERROR: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

How to solve this?

I installed it, but I don't know if I installed it correctly. I came to Linux to make better use of an environment focused on development, in this case to make full use of docker. I tried to follow chatgpt's suggestions, but it didn't work.

Comment: Preface the command with `sudo` in the short term. You might think about adding your user to the docker group in the long term. Personally I prefer to have to answer a sudo challenge though as there are some destructive docked commands.

Comment: `sudo usermod -aG docker YOUR_USER`   add your user to docker group . logout / login